# Join tables to find churn and new customer

Tags: sql, join, zoho

I am trying to create a table that would have current month sales and previous month sales next to each other. A problem I am having is it does not include the varid's if they do not have current sales. My final outcome would be a table similar to this.

```
Varid       Date     Current Month Billings Prior Month Billings
----------- -------- ---------------------- --------------------
1           1/1/2014 5                      4
2           1/1/2014 0                      4
3           2/1/2014 5                      0
4           3/1/2014 6                      4
5           3/1/2014 0                      4
6           6/1/2014 1                      0
```

I am using a program called zoho reports that does not allow a full join. So far my query reads like this:

```
SELECT
    TS."Var ID",
    TS."date",
     TS."CC Billings" as "current Month",
    COALESCE(TS2."CC BIllings", 0) AS "Prior Month Billings"
FROM
    "All Actual Billings" TS

LEFT OUTER JOIN "All Actual Billings" TS2 ON
    TS2."Var ID" = TS."Var ID" AND

        (TS2."date"= DATE_SUB(TS."date", INTERVAL 1 month) )
```

Database structure looks like this. 
[image]

Comment: It is almost impossible to make any suggestions about your query without seeing your database tables structure.

Comment: hello @AndyKorneyev please see the edit. I added an example of the database structure